# Como resolver objeto PHP duplicado?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho 2 objetos com valores diferentes, mas quando vou salvar ele salva como um único objeto.

Exemplo de como estou usando:

```
class Objeto {
    private $Nome;

    public function setNome($Nome){
        $this->Nome = $Nome;
    }

    public function getNome(){
        return $this->Nome;
    }
}

$objet2 = $obj1 = new Objeto();
$obj1->setNome("Pedro");
$objet2->setNome("Marcos");


salvar($obj1);
salvar($objet2);
```

Ele salva como o id do registro $obj1 mas com os dados de $objet2.

Comment: O que significa essa linha ? `$objet2 = $obj1 = new Objeto();`.

Comment: Acredito que o problema esteja nesta linha: `$objet2 = $obj1 = new Objeto();`. Você está criando uma instância pra dois objetos. Posso estar errado...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quando você usa `$objet2 = $obj1 = new Objeto();`, as duas variáveis estão apontando para o mesmo objeto.

Você pode dar um `echo` no atributo `Nome` de cada objeto e ver que sempre irá retornar "Marcos".

Exemplo:

```
class Objeto {
    private $Nome;

    public function setNome($Nome){
        $this->Nome = $Nome;
    }

    public function getNome(){
        return $this->Nome;
    }
}

$objet2 = $obj1 = new Objeto();
$obj1->setNome("Pedro");
$objet2->setNome("Marcos");

echo $obj1->getNome(); //Retorna Marcos
echo '<br />';
echo $objet2->getNome(); //Retorna Marcos
```

Edit:

A solução para o seu problema é simples, apenas crie um objeto para cada variável:

```
$obj1 = new Objetio();
$objet2 = new Objetio();
```

Answer (score 2):

Verifiquei, posso fazer um clone do meu objeto, assim esse novo objeto recebe uma nova referencia na memória.

```
class Objeto {
    private $Nome;

    public function setNome($Nome){
        $this->Nome = $Nome;
    }

    public function getNome(){
        return $this->Nome;
    }
}

$obj1 = new Objeto();
$objet2 = clone $obj1; // Clonando o objeto
$obj1->setNome("Pedro");
$objet2->setNome("Marcos");

echo $obj1->getNome(); //Retorna Marcos
echo '<br />';
echo $objet2->getNome(); //Retorna Marcos
```